# Accurate color blending in Matplotlib-Venn

Tags: python, matplotlib, venn-diagram, matplotlib-venn

With the following code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib_venn import venn2
from collections import OrderedDict

named_sets = {'x1': set(['foo','foo','bar',"pax"]), "x3" : set(['foo','qux','bar',"zoo"])}
od = OrderedDict(sorted(named_sets.iteritems()))

circlenm = ()
circlels = []
for k,v in od.iteritems():
    circlenm = circlenm + (k,)
    circlels.append(v)


c = venn2(subsets = circlels,set_labels = circlenm)
c.get_patch_by_id('10').set_color('red')
c.get_patch_by_id('01').set_color('blue')
c.get_patch_by_id('10').set_edgecolor('none')
c.get_patch_by_id('01').set_edgecolor('none')
c.get_patch_by_id('10').set_alpha(0.4)
c.get_patch_by_id('01').set_alpha(0.4)
plt.show()
```

I can get the following figure:

[image]

Here I'd like to blend circles of 'blue' with 'red'.
Notice that the result of the blending is **brown**.

But the actual value supposed to be **light magenta** (figure below is created using default `matplotlib_venn.venn3`):

[image]

How can I achieve that correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add these 3 lines to set the color and display properties of the intersection:

```
c.get_patch_by_id('11').set_color('magenta')
c.get_patch_by_id('11').set_edgecolor('none')
c.get_patch_by_id('11').set_alpha(0.4)
```

If you want an exact color then you can set like this:

```
c.get_patch_by_id('11').set_color('#e098e1')
```

The patch id is a bitmask showing which circles the area is inside.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the colors directly to `venn2` when creating the diagram via the `set_colors` argument, then it will do the color blending automatically:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib_venn import venn2
from collections import OrderedDict

named_sets = {'x1': set(['foo','foo','bar',"pax"]), "x3" : set(['foo','qux','bar',"zoo"])}

circlenm = ()
circlels = []

for k,v in named_sets.items():
    circlenm = circlenm + (k,)
    circlels.append(v)

c = venn2(
    subsets = circlels,
    set_labels = circlenm,
    set_colors=("red", "blue")
)
plt.show()
```

[image: colored venn diagram]